# Trouble Using a click event to send user input to the server

Tags: jquery, click, dom-events

I'm having some trouble putting together an event based on the clicking of the submit button. My goal is to run the function `Chat.send()` with the user input in the field at the top of the page when a user presses the "Send" button. Just to reiterate, I want to pass the string in the text bar to `Chat.send()` when a user clicks the send button. I'm pretty new to this and looking for a little direction. I took a hack at it but it isn't working at all..

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <script src="http://chatbuilder.hackreactor.com/ChatBuilder.js"></script>
      </head>
        <body>
          <script>
           Chat.guide.start();
          </script>


   <h2>Borken Chat</h2>

      <input class="draft" type="text"/> <button class="send" disabled>send</button>



<ul class="messages">

  <script>
     var Chat_Messages=[];

  function fetchNew() {
    var PrintChat=function(Chat_Messages){
    var y=Chat_Messages.length;
    for(i=0;i<y;i++){
      Chat.display(Chat_Messages[i]);
    }
    }
 Chat.fetch(PrintChat);
 }

 setInterval(fetchNew,3000);


 /*
 *$('#send').click(function(){
  var Input=<input class="draft" type="text">
  Chat.send(Input)
 }) **This was my attempt. I was trying to use the "send" button to trigger an event that calls Chat.fetch on a variable that I         was trying to define as the user input*/



  </script>

</ul>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need quotations around your markup when you assign it to your variable Input. That's not going to solve your problem as you need the actual value of that input field as user1846192 demonstrated. Just more of a public service announcement for js/jquery development.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function(){

  // <-- Stick the rest of your code here.

  $('.send').click(function(){      
    Chat.send($('.draft').val())
  });
});
```

Comment: It's also a good idea to get rid of the `disabled` attribute on the `.send` button, then it should work.

Comment: And if the above code is working, but your chat isn't working, then it might be a good idea to stick all of your JS, including the `Chat.guide.start();` inside the `$(document).ready(function(){})` bit. Edited the answer to clarify where that is.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's a pretty old question, but I was just able to figure it out (for the most part), so I thought I'd share what I did.  My main concern was how to get the text out of `<input class="draft" type="text"/>`.  I decided to just assign it a value like so  `<input class="draft" type="text" value=""/>`

and the rest of the code -

```
$('.send').on('click', function(){
var myMessage = $('.draft').val();
Chat.send(myMessage);
});
```

It sends to the server, but the only problem I'm having with it now is that the text i type won't disappear when .send is clicked. Shouldn't be too difficult to figure out.

Comment: Hi and hello to Stackoverflow. However your answer is essentially the same as Mathijs Flietstra's answer so it does not add much knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @LiamSchauerman I am very excited to be joining such an extraordinary group of individuals.